# Wrong number or types of arguments error using cursors with parameters

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I am getting this error trying to have an input parameter "var_city" in my cursor so I can use the user's input of a city.

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 17, column 5:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CUSTOMERS'
ORA-06550: line 17, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

p_city is commented out because I was trying to use that input parameter as the value used but it didn't work as well.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET VER OFF

-- ACCEPT p_city PROMPT 'Enter city name: '

DECLARE
    v_custname      si.customer.custname%TYPE;
    v_total_spent   NUMBER;
    v_total_cars    NUMBER;
    CURSOR customers (var_city varchar2) IS
    SELECT
        custname
    FROM
        si.customer
    WHERE
        UPPER(custcity) = UPPER(var_city);

BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('Customer Name'
                         || 'Total Cars'
                         || 'Total Spent');
    OPEN customers;
    LOOP
        FETCH customers INTO v_custname;
        EXIT WHEN customers%NOTFOUND;
        cust_total_spending_and_cars(v_custname, v_total_cars, v_total_spent);
        dbms_output.put_line(v_custname
                             || v_total_cars
                             || v_total_spent);
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE customers;
END;
/
```

Comment: FYI - your edit history is visible to people with sufficient rep. So in future you should take care to redact your code **before** posting it here, if you have any concerns. Although your original code seems innocuous enough, it's hard to imagine what corporate IP you think you've compromised.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that what you've done here counts as vandalism - you have removed any value in the question. I'm not going to rollback your edit - although I could - in order to give the chance to re-write your question so it's a proper question and fits the answer given by @JonHeller. But read the T&Cs - once you've posted a question here you no longer own it, it belongs to the StackOverflow community.

Comment: @APC It is a school assignment, once my teacher uses turnitin software to check for plagiarism this question may ring some bells even though it isn't asking for answers it will still make the plagiarism percentage be higher. I will rollback once I get my grade back.

Comment: Editing posts does not delete information.

Answer (score 3):

An argument must be passed to the `OPEN` statement

Change this line:

```
OPEN customers;
```

To something like this:

```
OPEN customers('city name here');
```